# i'm making some App with QCAR,JPCT-AE

Tags: android, qcar-sdk

Hi i'm making some App with QCAR & JPCT-AE. can SOMEONE see my source code & advice me? if you can, i'll send my source code to you. my email address is lyhdra99@gmail.com.

Please help me ^^

---

first

1. i send modelViewMatrix(QCAR::Matrix44F) from JNI to JAVA
   ex) JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_jp_may_com_VirtualButtonsRenderer_getNowMatrix(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
2. use this modelViewMatrix like below

---

```
public class VirtualButtonsRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {


    public VirtualButtonsRenderer(Activity act) {
        Config.maxAnimationSubSequences = 999;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.act = act;
        _Object3D = Loader.loadMD2(act.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tris), 1.0f);
        _Object3D.setName("MyTarget");
    }

    public native float[] getNowMatrix();

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        initRendering();
        QCAR.onSurfaceCreated();
        world = new World();
        world.setAmbientLight(20, 20, 20);
        TextureManager tm = TextureManager.getInstance();
        com.threed.jpct.Texture Cover = new com.threed.jpct.Texture(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(act.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skin)));
        tm.addTexture("Cover", Cover);          
        _Object3D.setTexture("Cover");
        world.addObject(_Object3D);
        world.buildAllObjects();
        sun = new Light(world);
        sun.setIntensity(250, 250, 250);        
        Camera cam = world.getCamera();
        cam.moveCamera(Camera.CAMERA_MOVEOUT, 100);
        cam.lookAt(_Object3D.getTransformedCenter());           
        SimpleVector sv = new SimpleVector();
        sv.set(_Object3D.getTransformedCenter());
        sv.x -= 300;
        sv.z -= 0;
        sun.setPosition(sv);
        MemoryHelper.compact(); 

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mIsActive)
            return;
        if (renderFrame()) {
            Matrix NowMatrix = new Matrix();
            NowMatrix.fillDump(getNowMatrix());
            world.getCamera().setBack(NowMatrix);
            world.renderScene(fb);          
            world.draw(fb);     
            fb.display();
            return;
        } else {
            mIsTouch = false;
        }
    }

}
```

---

here, i got problem. i thought Object3D can move like Teapot(QCAR Sample Object) on Marker with modelViewMatrix. but it couldn't.

this is my problem ^^;;

Comment: Do you have a specific issue that you can share with us?  If you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) we could help.

Comment: Does the object render when there is a trackable? It just doesn't move?

Answer (score 0):

i would like to help you with your app,
please send me your native imagetarget.cpp code,

before that i think you have seen this page ,refer this once

http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Integrating_JPCT-AE_with_Vuforia

its project source code
https://github.com/sidneibjunior/vuforia-jpct

fetch your modelViewMatrix from renderframe and send it to java , like this

const QCAR::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);

QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

SampleUtils::rotatePoseMatrix(90.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);

//inversing the matrix
QCAR::Matrix44F inverseMV = SampleMath::Matrix44FInverse(modelViewMatrix);

//transposing the inverted matrix
QCAR::Matrix44F invTranspMV = SampleMath::Matrix44FTranspose(inverseMV);

send the inverse transpose matrix to java code. It will work fine... i hope :)